# TensorFlow - Deep MNIST - exit code 139

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run the following example code for the Deep MNIST example provided by TensorFlow but I get an error when I run it. The first part of the code runs fine and prints out the accuracy for the test with the GradientDescentOptimizer. The second part fails at the last line where it prints the test accuracy for the convolutional network. The program finishes with the following line: "**Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)**"

I have tried both Python 3 and 3.5 but I get the same error with both of them.

**Update:** I noticed that if I exchange **mnist.test.images** and **mnist.test.labels** to **batch[0]** and **batch[1]** in the final print statement that segfaults, and generate a new batch just prior to the print with: "`batch = mnist.test.next_batch(50)`" it works fine.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

for _ in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                          strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(
        feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

**EDIT**: This is what I get when using python3.5 with gdb to run the program and showing the frame and backtrace: (Also a link to the same output on hastebin: https://hastebin.com/ulaqidogol.cpp)

```
Thread 6 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff2a55700 (LWP 13640)]
0x00007fffe7b56d99 in Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_lhs<float, long, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, 8, 4, 0, false, false>::operator()(float*, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer> const&, long, long, long, long) ()
   from /home/jimmy/.virtualenvs/TensorFlowTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7ffff2a54d00:
 rip = 0x7fffe7b56d99
    in Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_lhs<float, long, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, 8, 4, 0, false, false>::operator()(float*, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer> const&, long, long, long, long); saved rip = 0x7fffe7b65fba
 called by frame at 0x7ffff2a54e00
 Arglist at 0x7ffff2a54cf0, args: 
 Locals at 0x7ffff2a54cf0, Previous frame's sp is 0x7ffff2a54d00
 Saved registers:
  rbx at 0x7ffff2a54cc8, rbp at 0x7ffff2a54cf0, r12 at 0x7ffff2a54cd0, r13 at 0x7ffff2a54cd8, r14 at 0x7ffff2a54ce0, r15 at 0x7ffff2a54ce8, rip at 0x7ffff2a54cf8
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fffe7b56d99 in Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_lhs<float, long, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, 8, 4, 0, false, false>::operator()(float*, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer> const&, long, long, long, long) ()
   from /home/jimmy/.virtualenvs/TensorFlowTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#1  0x00007fffe7b65fba in Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorContractionOp<Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<long>, 1ul> const, Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorImagePatchOp<-1l, -1l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const> const, Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>::Context<Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_lhs<float, long, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, 8, 4, 0, false, false>, Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_rhs<float, long, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionSubMapper<float, long, 0, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorImagePatchOp<-1l, -1l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, 4, 0, false, false>, Eigen::internal::gebp_kernel<float, float, long, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<float, long, 0, 0>, 8, 4, false, false>, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionInputMapper<float, long, 1, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, Eigen::internal::TensorContractionInputMapper<float, long, 0, Eigen::TensorEvaluator<Eigen::TensorReshapingOp<Eigen::DSizes<long, 2> const, Eigen::TensorImagePatchOp<-1l, -1l, Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float const, 4, 1, long>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> const> const> const, Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, Eigen::array<long, 1ul>, 4, true, false, 0, Eigen::MakePointer>, Eigen::internal::blas_data_mapper<float, long, 0, 0> >::enqueue_packing_helper(long, long, long, bool) ()
   from /home/jimmy/.virtualenvs/TensorFlowTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
#2  0x00007fffe4b33e22 in Eigen::NonBlockingThreadPoolTempl<tensorflow::thread::EigenEnvironment>::WorkerLoop(int) ()
   from /home/jimmy/.virtualenvs/TensorFlowTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
#3  0x00007fffe4b32ed2 in std::_Function_handler<void (), tensorflow::thread::EigenEnvironment::CreateThread(std::function<void ()>)::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) ()
   from /home/jimmy/.virtualenvs/TensorFlowTest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so
#4  0x00007fffe4150e20 in std::execute_native_thread_routine_compat (__p=<optimized out>) at /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:110
#5  0x00007ffff76f908a in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff743047f in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Can you run with gdb and print the stack at the segfault point?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos : I'm not experienced with gdb and a bit unsure how I print the stack. I start python with gdb and run my program. What should I write when I see the Segmentation fault?

Comment: Can you file a github issue? This stack looks like an eigen bug or a tensorflow memory management bug.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Okey, I've opened a new issue on Github now.